# OneDrive API to CMIS library

Tags: open-source, library, cmis, ecm, office365

I am looking for a software library that would take [Office365's legacy OneDrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh826521.aspx) and offer access via the modern [CMIS API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) on top of it instead.

That would allow standard CMIS clients to access data from OneDrive/Office365.

```
Office365 <--------------------- the library <----------------- CMIS client
             OneDrive protocol                  CMIS protocol
```

Requirement:

- Open-source